# Ruby Object manipulation

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, mongomapper

We have an algorithm that compare ruby objects coming from MongoDB. The majority of the time spent, it taking the results (~1000), assigning a weight to them, and comparing them to a base object. This process takes ~2 sec for 1000 objects. Afterwards, we order the objects by the weight, and take the top 10.

Given that the number of initial matches will continue to grow, I'm looking for more efficient ways to compare and sort matches in Ruby.

I know this is kind of vague, but let's assume they are User objects that have arrays of data about the person and we're comparing them to a single user to find the best match for that user.

Comment: You're right, that's totally unclear.

Comment: what exactly is the comparison process you are currently using?

Comment: The comparison is between sets of arrays that contain strings for each user. Basically find out how many elements they have in common for each array, and there are a total of maybe 5 array comparisons.

Comment: This is really a much larger algorithmic question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered storing/caching the weight? This works well if the weight depends only on the attributes of each user and not on values external to that user.

Also, how complex is the calculation involving the weight associated with a user and the "base" user? If it's complex you may want to consider using a graph database, which can store data that is specific to the relation between 2 nodes/objects.

Comment: Good point. The comparison it between a variety of arrays associated with each user. They change, but not a ton. So something like, UserA has connections = [....] and UserB has connections = [...]. The connections array just has string IDs in it. So it'll compare the 2 and find out how many connections they have in common. As I mentioned, the connections are updated each night, but they likely don't change A LOT.